# Increasing elements in vector in R

Tags: r, vector, resize

I have a vector that I would like to increase the elements based on another vector.
How can I increase the elements in my vector without having to manually type it out?
I want to use the two vectors

````
NumberofTimes<-c(4,1,2,3)
Spread<-c(0.060,0.170,0.140,0.070)
```
I.e. I want a vector with 4 of the 0.060, 1 of the 0.170, 2 of the 0.140, etc.
Instead of writing: 
  
```
Spread<-c(0.060,0.060,0.060,0.060,0.170,0.140,0.140,0.070,0.070,0.070)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Base R `rep` function with times argument

```r
> rep(Spread, times = NumberofTimes)
 [1] 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.17 0.14 0.14 0.07 0.07 0.07
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this using `mapply()` and a function with `rep()` to wrap sequences between `Spread` and `NumberofTimes`. Here the code:

```
#Data
NumberofTimes<-c(4,1,2,3)
Spread<-c(0.060,0.170,0.140,0.070)
#Apply
vecval <- unlist(mapply(function(x,y) rep(x,y),x=Spread,y=NumberofTimes))
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.17 0.14 0.14 0.07 0.07 0.07
```

Answer (score -1):

An option with `Map`

```
unlist(Map(rep, Spread, NumberofTimes))
```